# Google Fit API works only in specific conditions

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth, google-fit, google-fit-api

I have set up Google Fit API in my Android application coded in Java. It works perfectly when I debug the code on the phone directly connected to the computer. I've tried with multiple devices and everything is working well. When I build the apk, it does not work.
Since I need to show the app to the client who is far away, I tried sending the source code to his computer and debugging from there. Even everything is same, it does not work on his device. Google Fit just stops after selecting the account, returning the response "CANCELED 0". Google Cloud Console has testing status, and all of the accounts used to test Google Fit are added as testers. Is Google Fit somehow limited or I am missing some crucial detail?

Comment: Is the issue reproducible on your end? If so, could you provide the error logs from Logcat so we can analyze what's going on. Also make sure the problematic device has Google Play services. If it still persists, try clearing the cache of Google Play Services.